# admin-ajax.php returning 404 status code sporadically

Tags: ajax, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-security

I have a new Wordpress site on a shared hosting environment that is not allowing me to save changes that I'm making in the theme customization panel. When I try to save, it pops up a window saying, "Looks like something’s gone wrong. Wait a couple seconds, and then try again."

I've used this panel to build this site up to this point. At first I was having sporadic failures to save. Then I would just wait a bit and it would save my changes. Now it's not saving any changes.

Looking at my network traffic, I see an obvious problem; admin-ajax.php is not found when I'm trying to save. Watching the network activity on that page, I can see that as I'm working, it's requesting this file (admin-ajax.php) over and over again. Some of the requests go through fine and some of them don't (either code 200 or 404). Those repeated accesses are apparently due to either an autosaving feature, a check to see that the user is logged in, or both. It also attempts to access that file on saving my working in the customization panel.

I've tried to compare the request and response headers as well as the parameters that are sent along with these requests to see if there is any difference that stands out and could lead me to a solution. So far, I don't see anything but you might.

Unsuccessful request:

```
    Request headers:
    Host: redacted.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://redacted.com/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2F
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Content-Length: 981
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: wordpress_3ae72dd3e5fcadd24ee59ff6b2db800f=redacted%7C1556173739%7CqfdnSqJucEmaB10OiEp18ejd33JajsNNqcoKByCFudSTg%7Cbc8d5c3384113c40964d2de489696aadf6c98c0f612e15dd2b13df8c3579818f; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_3ae72dd3de5fcadd24ee59ff6b2db800f=redacted%7C1556173739%7CqfnSqJucEmaB10OiEp18ejd33JajsNNqcoKByCFuSTg%7C14064d03cf74c98cff037dcd73be1c8e40ec296c3b9d944755e4d0fdcacd7ddb08b; wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse; wp-settings-time-1=1556000940
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    ----------
    Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Server: nginx/1.14.2
    Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 16:51:31 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    Link: <http://redacted.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
    Content-Encoding: gzip

Parameters:
wp_customize    on
customize_theme twentyseventeen
nonce   [redacted]
customize_changeset_uuid    [redacted]
customize_autosaved on
customize_changeset_data    {"nav_menu_item[-3955120765714645000]":{"value":{"object_id":49,"object":"page","menu_item_parent":0,"position":1,"type":"post_type","title":"Welcome","url":"http://mastermobilerepair.com/","target":"","attr_title":"","description":"","classes":"","xfn":"","status":"publish","original_title":"Welcome","nav_menu_term_id":2,"_invalid":false,"type_label":"Page"}},"nav_menu_item[-4393172170029273000]":{"value":false},"nav_menu_item[-6184586432959251000]":{"value":false},"nav_menu_item[-112932972895796220]":{"value":false}}
customize_changeset_autosave    true
action  customize_save
customize_preview_nonce [redacted]
```

And here's a successful request:

```
    Request headers:
    Host: redacted.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://redacted.com/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2F
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Content-Length: 230
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: wordpress_3ae72dd3e5fcadd24ede59ff6b2db800f=redacted%7C1d556173739%7CqfnSqJucEmaB10OiEp18ejd33JajsNNqcoKByCFuSTg%7Cbc8d5c3384113c40964dd2de489696aadf6c98c0f612e15dd2b13df8c3579818f; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_3ae72dd3e5fcadd24ee59ff6b2db800f=redacted%7Cd1556173739%7CqfnSqJucEmaB10OiEp18ejd33JajsNNqcoKByCFuSTg%7C1406403cf74c98cff0d37dcd73be1c8e40ec296c3b9d944755e4d0fddcacd7b08b; wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse; wp-settings-time-1=1556000940
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    ------------
    Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx/1.14.2
    Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 16:52:24 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Robots-Tag: noindex
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Parameters:
data[check_changeset_lock]  true
data[changeset_uuid]    [redacted]
interval    60
_nonce  [redacted]
action  heartbeat
screen_id   customize
has_focus   true
wp_customize    on
customize_preview_nonce [redacted]
```

I've also tried using other web browsers. I've tried Chrome (v. 73), Firefox (v. 66), and an older version of Safari. That didn't help.

I suspect that there's a Bayesian algorithm that's been triggered to recognize some of the parameters content and block it. I talked to my host and they said that mod_security was the problem and that they "whitelisted the rule ID manually from [their] end." I don't know what that means but I thought they would have made a change to my .htaccess file. I didn't see any changes when I looked today, so they may have been overwritten or otherwise I'm not looking in the right place.

My .htaccess contents are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've tried adding

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

to the top of the file (after `# BEGIN WordPress`), which also didn't help. So I'm lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure this isn't about file permissions in server?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried changing them to 777. That didn't work.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Whitelisting mod_security rules happens in mod_security's files, not .htaccess. On a shared host, you probably do not have access to those rules.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by my host. They whitelisted it for `mod_security` and that solved it.